# What is the maximum length of Version in Flyway database deployment scripts

Tags: flyway

on Flyway deployment script name starts with a version.

What is the maximum length one can use? I see that on the table column holding the version is 50 character long

Comment: As Dennis pointed out, it is a good idea to do as much research as possible and show what you have found. Then if you have problems using the information you found which doesn't meet you expectations you can update the question with your findings.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of limits:

- Version must be 50 characters or less
- Description must be 200 characters or less
- Migration filenames must be compatible with any OS limit

Do you have a specific use case for a version string longer than 50 characters? We're in the middle of work for Flyway 7 and this is a chance for us to change the history table *if* there's a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [documentation located here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#versioned-migrations), you'll find that the limit is not one from Flyway. Rather, your limit on the length of the version is based on the OS and it's limit on the size of a file name. You must ensure that you're incrementing your numbers in an appropriate order. However, as you can see in the docs, Flyway supports a wide variety of formats, and the length of your string defining the version number is not an issue you need to worry about.

Comment: I beg to differ.  

It is dependent on the flyway history table version column. 

I found it to be 50 character long however In the documentation shows maximum of 19 characters.  

I say the limit is 50 character. 

In Linux file names can be much longer than 50 characters so file name is not an issue.